# Excel VBA, faster, cleaner way to find matching values/index match and return value from another column?

Tags: excel, match, vba

The code I've written below to replace some index match formulas in a sheet. It seems to work well enough, but I think the loop is a bit clumsy and may be prone to errors. Does anyone have any recommended improvements?

```
Sub match_SIC_code_sheet_loop()

'sic code needs to match value in column j or a in sic code sheet, '
'if not available = met10 works, but probably needs a bit more
'debugging to make it robust.

Dim ws As Integer
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastrow_sic As Long
Dim output_wb As Workbook
Dim SIC_sheet As Worksheet
Dim Demand_CAT As String
Dim sic_DMA As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim row As Integer
Dim WS_count As Long
Dim x As String
Dim y As String

Set output_wb = Workbooks("DMA_customers_SICTEST.xlsx") 'use thisworkbook instead
Set SIC_sheet = Workbooks("DMA_metered_tool_v12_SICTEST.xlsm").Sheets("SIC codes")

With SIC_sheet 'count the number of SIC codes to search through
    lastrow_sic = .Range("j" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
End With

With output_wb 'count the no. of sheets in the generated customer workbook
    WS_count = output_wb.Worksheets.Count
End With

With output_wb
    For ws = 1 To WS_count 'loop through each sheet in the customer workbook
        With output_wb.Sheets(ws)
            y = output_wb.Sheets(ws).Name
            lastrow = .Range("a" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row ' number of rows in the
            'current customer sheet
            For i = 2 To lastrow 'data starts in row 2; sic code in column 9
                sic_DMA = .Cells(i, 9).Text 'the lookup value
                With SIC_sheet
                'SIC codes start in row 2, if the sic code matches,
                'the correct demand category is appointed, if the sic code does not
                'match, then MET_10 is given as the default value.
                    For row = 2 To lastrow_sic
                        x = .Cells(row, 3).Text
                        If x = sic_DMA Then
                            Demand_CAT = .Cells(row, 10).Text
                        Exit For
                        Else
                            Demand_CAT = "MET_10"
                        End If
                    Next row
                output_wb.Sheets(ws).Cells(i, 23).Value = Demand_CAT
                End With
            Next i
        End With
    Next ws
End With
output_wb.Save
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: This may be a better fit for the Code Review SE site: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks @nwhaught. I didn't know there was a review site, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

For starters you could break that long procedure into a few smaller methods. For example you could have a ProcessSheet procedure into which you pass each sheet under :

```
For ws = 1 To WS_count 'loop through each sheet in the customer workbook
```

That would definitely help readability etc. If you're still not satisfied then continue breaking the loop into smaller logical procedures. Just don't go too crazy.

Apart from that some error checking and value validation would go a long way in a deeply nested loop. For example ensure that various calculated variables such as 'lastrow' are correct or within a valid threshold etc.

Finally instead of hardcoded values sprinkled through your long loop like magically camoflauged debug-from-hell-where's-waldo fairies; prefer instead a few meaningfully named Const variable alternatives i.e.

```
Private Const SIC_START_ROW = 2
```

Comment: Cheers @DanoThom. You're right I should have split the procedure up into more sizeable chunks. I use the locals window in my debugging, is there a better way?

Comment: Better way for what in the locals window?

Comment: Checking that your variables are set to what you expect them to be.

Comment: Oh, no I meant programmatically drop in a few 'if' statements to check the variables before they're utilized etc.